# Crystal Reports Rows in Group

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a report grouped by Supplier.  In the details section for this group, there are customer names with other fields of information.  The problem is that a customer may be listed several times, but I only want one record to show per customer.

**Supplier**

```
John Doe   10/15   $25.00  Eggs
John Doe   10/15   $29.00  Milk
Susan Weva 10/12   $15.00  Corn 
Susan Weva 10/18   $11.00  Bread
```

What I want is one complete row for **John Doe** and one for **Susan Weva**.  Any idea as to how I can do this?  I tried to suppress each field, but that did not seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

There is one way (which i use in this situations) and it work.

So your data looks like this

```
John Doe   10/15   $25.00  Eggs
John Doe   10/15   $29.00  Milk
Susan Weva 10/12   $15.00  Corn 
Susan Weva 10/18   $11.00  Bread
```

From what i have understand you want to have your output like

```
John Doe   some columns
Susan Weva some columns
```

To show it only once per group put fields in group header or group footer. In your case all other columns are different and you should "summarize" those fields. For field price is easy, just do summarize by group and you have for each person amount. But dates and last columns makes a problem. So you should learn about using Cross-tab to solve this problem. If you need only sum of price, then put fields in group header or group footer and it will be show only once per group.

Hope it helps

Comment: Okay.  Thanks for your suggestion.  I appreciate the help.